# How can I list all hosts on my network with the time and/or date that they connected to the network?

Tags: networking, scripting, security

Regarding the situational context, long story short, a family member did a dumb thing, and I need to increase the capabilities of my network monitoring system.

Is there a way to create a log of the time and/or date at which devices attempt to perform a 3-way TCP handshake (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK) with my router, through the implementation of nmap, tcpdump, or some other similar tool?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you please very precisely define what you mean with "most recently connected"? What constitutes "connecting"?

Comment: "When did the device last join the network?"


For example, assuming a laptop is on the network, then gets taken to a different location, out of range of the network, the time I'm looking for would be the time at which it gets back in range and joins the network again.

Comment: Sorry, this just shifts the semantic load from "connecting" to "joining". What consitutes "joining"? Especially in the context of wireless networks (first time you mention that!) that's not a clear term. I think there might be more happening under the hood of a wireless device than you realize. What's the action you actually care about?

Comment: Thought: maybe it would help if you actually wrote out in a definite manner what the *goal* of this monitoring is – I guess there's something you want to detect *based* on the "joining" (however we defined that).

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`arpwatch`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/arpwatch.8.html)?

Comment: Or a DHCP bootp request?

Comment: hui, your new question is a lot different than the original one! Glad I've asked!

Comment: are you sure that's what you want to ask about? It's very rare that clients make TCP connections *with* your router. Maybe you meant *through* the router? Either way, no, you cannot know this externally, you need to run your observation *on* the router.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 

Yh, sometimes I need the frustration of people not having a clue what I'm on about to kick the technical side of my brain into action. 

I'm so used to having to deal with non-technical people, the non-technical description of things is my default go-to these days.

Comment: @MarcusMüller

So there's no way to do it from a linux computer on the network, it definitely HAS to be done on the router?

Comment: @Lee exactly, as I wrote; other machines than your router don't see the packets going to, from, your router.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, I'll see what I can sort out.

Comment: @MarcusMüller

I've been working today, so I've not had as much time as I would have liked to look on here or to think the issue through, as I've been too busy dealing with issues at work. 

BUT I think I've just figured out how I could do it without capturing the TCP Handshake.

I'll post the solution when I finish for the day. I need to test the theory before I submit it.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you found a solution to sniff on a connection between two devices that does not involve the device you're sniffing with ;) That's not how modern networks work.

Comment: Just finished work for the day. Gonna have a break for an hour, then sit down and focus my full attention on this.